# build a model capturing related features for multiple events

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, deep-learning, latent-variable

There is a data set, which has about 20000 data points. Each data point has about 100 features. At the same time, there is an instance set, including 60 different instances. Right now, there is a manually labelling process, which can assign 0, one or more instances to each data point. For instance, data point 1 can have no instance to be assigned; while data point 100 can have instance 20 and instance 30 being assigned.

Based on this labeling set, how to build a model that can capture the relationship between those 100 features with these different 60 instances. Generally, instance x should be a function of instances a, b and c. The function can be of traditional statistical models, like logistic regression, or even may be some latest development, like deep learning.
In accordance with the above discussion, what are the possible model candidates, either statistical ones or machine learning ones?

Comment: This question is overly broad. You appear to be asking how to organize an analysis strategy when multiple methods might be used and likely need to be compared.

Comment: Hi David, as you said, there may have multiple methods available to solve this question. I am curious to know what are the most powerful or state-of-the-art model that can be used to attack this kind of problem.